# Get Next Value from a SQL Server Sequence via Remote Database Link from Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a sequence in my SQL Server database. I am using ODBC Driver 17 installed on my Oracle server to connect to the SQL Server instance. When I run

```
select "ADDRESS_SEQ".nextval@SQLLINK from dual
```

I get the error:

> ORA-02070: database SQLLINK does not support sequence references in this context.

Creating a synonym and selecting nextval from that synonym results in the same error message.

How can I access a SQL Server sequence from an Oracle database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the call to

```
select next value for ADDRESS_SEQ
```

in a custom SQL Server stored procedure, use [Passthrough SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/heter/passthrough-sql.html#GUID-C03895FB-EE60-4F71-8943-994C185C2EB2), or call the [sp_sequence_get_range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) system stored procedure.